# cordova / phonegap app, screen jumping by about 15px when loading

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

ive made a phonegap / cordova 1.7 app its all working fine but when ever i go to load a page it loads it about 15px too low and then jumps up.. this only takes part of a second but the jump is noticable to the eye. i think that it has somthing to do with the status bar being hidden ive hidden it using the `Status bar is initially hidden : YES` in the plist, which i believe only hides it on load rather than having it perminetly hidden..

is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS correct, is this only on an iPad? Do you have a launch image set? If so, you need to heed Apple's guidelines about the correct dimensions of the launch image and make it 20px higher than it should be. You should be seeing a 20px jump, not 15px. For Retina displays, you need to make the launch image 40px higher than Apple's guidelines.

Let me dig up a link that confirms this behavior. I just went through it myself.

edit: here's the link [Phonegap iPad App Splash / Launch Screen Shifts on deviceReady](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476129/phonegap-ipad-app-splash-launch-screen-shifts-on-deviceready)

In my iOS Cordova app, making the launch image 20px higher than the guidelines (non-Retina) and 40px higher than the guidelines (Retina) fixed the issue. The only thing that remains is a warning in Xcode that the size of the image is incorrect. However it still works and Apple doesn't reject due to this.

Comment: its must be 20px, 15px was just a guess of how far it was jumping, this is happening on all of my pages, not just the splash screen, is that expected ? Do i simply make all of them bigger ?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

The above code snippet (written in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* method) initially hides the iPad status bar while the splash screen is running.

Now place the following code in *webViewDidFinishLoad* method to show the status bar after loading the application

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden: withAnimation:)])
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
    else 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

*Note:* Adjust the body css accordingly (I placed top:20px to adjust the body position)

Thanks,
Prodeveloper.

Answer (score 0):

I just made my application splash screen image 20px bigger, and now it is working fine.